# Android ADB: Device unauthorized trying to connect to a port-forwarded remote emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb

**Background:**
I recently upgraded to an AMD processor and found that the Android device emulator was complaining about not having hardware acceleration. (This is an issue for another question). My old Intel computer worked fine, so I decided to run the emulator on the old Intel PC (emu-pc) and use my new AMD computer (dev-pc) to code.

**Problem:**
I wasn't able to directly have the emulator expose its ports on the emu-pc to connect to via adb on the dev-pc (again an issue for another question), so I installed the Windows 10 OpenSSH server ([Microsoft instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse)) and connected to it from my dev-pc, forwarding the proper ADB ports:

`ssh {you}@<{remote ip} -L 5554:localhost:5554 -L 5555:localhost:5555`

I then tried connecting to the remote emulator via adb:
`adb connect localhost`

I was met with

```
$ ./adb devices
List of devices attached
localhost:5555  unauthorized
```

I've tried a few of the posts stating you should disable and re-enable USB debugging or revoke all the USB debugging authorization or use the "Wipe Data" option in the AVD Manager. None of these worked. I also tried messing with the adbkeys on the emulator under `/data/misc/adb/adbkeys` but I get permission denied trying to do anything to that file. (I also can't `ls` it via an `adb shell`)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I found something that worked for me. I was able to telnet to the emu-pc via port 5554, where I tried to auth on the Android console. The login message said:

```
Android Console: type 'auth <auth_token>' to authenticate
Android Console: you can find your <auth_token> in
'C:\Users\exile57\.emulator_console_auth_token'
```

I found that file and was able to log in. This made me think that the emulator thinks the connection is coming from the emu-pc, yet the keys that I was using were generated on the dev-pc. I found the keys on emu-pc in `C:\Users\[your user]\.android` as `adbkey` and `adbkey.pub`. I copied those to the dev-pc, killed the adb server, disconnected all devices, then tried reconnecting:

```
$ ./adb disconnect
./adb kill-server
./adb connect localhost
```

After a bit, I was able to connect and drive the device over adb:

```
$ ./adb devices
List of devices attached
localhost:5555  device
```

**NOTE** I'm not sure this is the whole story, as when testing this out for this answer, I deleted the dev-pc's adbkey and adbkey,pub and was still able to reconnect, so that seems a bit strange. It worked for me, but be aware, I'm not sure the mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I did it:

1. First you need to run the emulator on the host computer. I used Android Studio and I had to close it because I noticed that the adb process kept spawning.
2. Start port-forwarding using SSH in the development computer.

```
ssh -L 5554:localhost:5554 -L 5555:localhost:5555 user@emulator-host-ip
```

3. copy adbkey and adbkey.pub files found at: `C:\Users\[your user]\.android` from the host computer to the development computer. this step should get ride of the unauthorized problem
4. in the development computer kill the adb server and lookup connected devices:

```
$ ./adb kill-server
$ ./adb devices
List of devices attached
localhost:5555  device
```

Answer (score 0):

In Android studio, Run menu > Run shows OFFLINE ... for the connected device.

Below is the procedure followed to solve it:

1. (Read the below note first) Delete the ~/.android/adbkey (or, rename to ~/.android/adbkey2, this is even better incase you want it back for some reason)
   Note: I happened to do this step, but it didn't solve the problem, after doing all the below steps it worked, so unsure if this step is required.
2. Run locate platform-tools/adb
   Note: use the path that comes from here in below commands
3. Kill adb server:
   sudo ~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb kill-server
4. You will get a Allow accept.. message popup on your device. Accept it. This is important, which solves the problem.
5. Start adb server:
   sudo ~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb start-server
6. In Android studio, do Run menu > Run again
   It will show something like Samsung ... (your phone manufacture name).
   Also installs the apk on device correctly this time without error.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I did try that procedure, but I never got the "Allow accept..." message on the remote emulator...